# the sycophant card

Tags: agricola

We need an impartial explanation on how to use this card "the SYCOPHANT". The card states " Any other player that uses the take 1 grain action space must first pay you one food. In addition, you receive 1 food from the supply, even when you take the grain yourself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whenever anyone takes the "Take 1 Grain" action space, they must first pay the Sycophant 1 food. After receiving this payment, the Sycophant then (also) receives 1 food from the supply.

When the Sycophant uses the "Take 1 Grain" action space, they (also) receive 1 food from the supply.

Source: compendium v9.0

Answer (score -2):

who intrepreted this card this way? For myself i understand it that the person who takes a grain must first pay a food to the player with the sycophant card. The owner of the card will get a grain themselves out of the supply when they take a grain for themselves. It's very clear to me. I challenge this. Is this a tournament rule ?

Comment: What are you challenging? The card is clear: "In addition" so it's on top of the payment, made even more clear with "even when you take the grain yourself" clarifying that this applies even when you take it and not another player.

Comment: yes exactly. In addition to the other player paying a food, the additional benefit of the card is that even when you take a grain for yourself you get paid a food from the supply. Anyone else agree with this intrepretation?

Comment: You can clearly see that the answer is "no". As I explained, "even" implies that that extra grain is not just for when you take the action.

Comment: to make that true , there would have to  be a period after " you recieve one food from supply" BUT since it's a comma,  it' s a continuation of the same thought.

Comment: The second sentence would have been simpler: You receive 1 food from the supply when you take the grain yourself.

Comment: thank you. That's my point. It doesn't say you also take a grain from the supply when someone else uses the card.

Comment: No, that isn't your point - if you were right it would have written as my last comment but you're obviously not because it's written the way it is.